# After upgrading the "lightning-base-components": "^1.18.8-ssr", getting error shadowSupportMode static property is not available in this environment

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

After upgrading the "lightning-base-components" to version "^1.18.8-ssr", getting the below error

Uncaught Error: Assert Violation: LightningRadioGroup is an invalid LWC component. The shadowSupportMode static property is not available in this environment.

Great appreciate it if someone had this issue and had a solution.